# Sum of smallest roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, contest-math

> If 2 and -3 are the roots of a biquadratic equation, then the sum of the two smallest
>   roots of this equation is: $\{-1, -3, -5, \text{cannot be determined} \}$ those are the options.

The answer key says **C** = $-5$.

But,

$P(x) = (x-2)(x+3)(f(x))$ where $f(x)$ has degree two.

It is possible to have: $P(x) = (x-2)(x+3)(x+2)(x-3)$ which gives $-5$ but there are other options such as:

$P(x) = (x-2)(x+3)(x+1999919199919912919199191)(x+1919359237597373792397)$

What is it then?

Comment: Can it be that by a "biquadratic equation" the book means an equation of the form $ax^4 + bx^2 + c = 0$, not a general quartic?

Comment: If biquadratic equation is quartic than this is utterly undeterminible.  But if biquadratic means quadratic equation as in form $ax^4 + bx^2 + c$ then there will be (usually) two solutions for $x^2$ which in turn will have (usually) two solutions.  Your counter example won't work in this case.  But with insight it is clear what the other two solutions must be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Biquartic functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quartic_function#Biquadratic_equations) have the form 
$$
Q(z)=a_4z^4+a_2z^2+a_0
$$
Each solution $z_\pm(\neq 0)$ of $Q(z)=0$ splits in two: $\pm\sqrt{z_\pm}$.

So when $2$ and $-3$ are root, $-2$ and $3$ are too, so the sum of the smallest is $-5$.